# How can I change arrow direction on Facebook comment window

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm using facebook API for like button. After pressing "Like" It appears comment window. 
[image]

As you can see It appears under the button. Can I change it? I need it to above the button? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Facebook Like button mark-up and styles are provided by Facebook’s servers, so you have no control over them. This is mainly to protect their “look” and brand, so it’s consistent no matter what website it is placed on.